# VS Code: Settings Sync - using office and home profiles

Tags: visual-studio-code, sync-settings

I have default profile for home and work and use remote explorer mainly.  Settings sync is on and I am logged in using github on both worstations.

Problem: My remotes ssh config is not synching in a way that gives me a unified set of servers.  Both have individual items i've added to each.

The json is

```
{
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "genieai.openai.temperature": 0.5,
    "genieai.enableConversationHistory": true,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "genieai.openai.model": "gpt-4",
    "terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false,
    "settingsSync.ignoredExtensions": []
}
```

Any tips?

Tried:

- All sync items appear to be included in sync in the sync settings.
- I've tried logout and back in seeking a message of something like 'do you want to import your settings..?'